# i have initialized but still got Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android

i got this error message

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example.asus.cataloguemovieuiux.model.MovieResponse.getResults()' on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.asus.cataloguemovieuiux.fragment.PlayingFragment$1.onResponse(PlayingFragment.java:83)
>                         at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)

i have checked to Movie class and there's no something wrong, and also checked on MovieResponse class. i'm so confused. why it's return to NullPointerException?
here's the code of method that got error :(

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, getResources().getString(R.string.loading_dialog), true, false);
    movieResponse = client.getInterface().getNowPlaying(BuildConfig.API_KEY);
    movieResponse.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
            List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getContext(), movies));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

on line

List movies = response.body().getResults();

Comment: `response.body()` is null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: yeah, check if the request was successful (response.isSuccessful()), nullity checks etc. Probably the API path is wrong, or the API key invalid.

Comment: You might be getting null `response`, you can debug by putting breakpoint on that line and check if `response` is null.

Comment: why it's turn to null?

Comment: Probably your MovieResponse class does not map correctly the server's response. You can use this tool, for example: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate the class automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that your error is caused when you're trying to change your List 'movies'. Check to see if response.body().getResults() is null.

Comment: why it's turn to null? i have initialize List<Movie> on MovieResponse

Comment: Your response body may be null.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for null by wrapping your code with if statement as below;

```
if (response.body() != null){
    List<Movies> movies = response.body().getResults();
}
```